# Parsing Receipt XML with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm working on a Windows Store app that uses in-store purchases. When a purchase is made, some XML is returned. I'm trying to see if the user successfully purchased the product. I know I can determine this with LINQ, but I'm not sure how to write my LINQ query.

```
private bool WasProductPurchasedFromStore(string productName)
{
        string data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Receipt Version=\"1.0\" ReceiptDate=\"2012-11-24T12:22:20Z\" CertificateId=\"\" ReceiptDeviceId=\"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa\"><ProductReceipt Id=\"bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb\" AppId=\"MyNamespace.MyApp_t7396xywk1mky\" ProductId=\"Upgrade\" PurchaseDate=\"2012-11-24T12:22:20Z\" ProductType=\"Durable\"  /></Receipt>";
  XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(data);

  // Return true if the productName is found in the XML.
  // THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK
  var result = from receipt in xml
               select receipt;

  // Return false if the user did not make the purchase
  return false;
}
```

How do I query my xml to see if there is a `ProductReceipt` element that has a `ProductId` attribute value that matches the value in `productName`?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this if you always know that the element and attribute will be there:

```
bool result = xml.Descendants("ProductReceipt")
    .Attributes().Single(x => x.Name == "ProductId")
    .Value == productName;
```

If the elements and attributes can be missing you can do SingleOrDefault and null check each step

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your product name is in the `AppId` attribute, that's what I'd do

```
private bool WasProductPurchasedFromStore(string productName)
{
    string data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Receipt Version=\"1.0\" ReceiptDate=\"2012-11-24T12:22:20Z\" CertificateId=\"\" ReceiptDeviceId=\"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa\"><ProductReceipt Id=\"bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb\" AppId=\"MyNamespace.MyApp_t7396xywk1mky\" ProductId=\"Upgrade\" PurchaseDate=\"2012-11-24T12:22:20Z\" ProductType=\"Durable\"  /></Receipt>";
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(data);

    return xml.Descendants("ProductReceipt")
        .Any(e => string.Compare(e.Attribute("AppId").Value, productName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = from productReceipt in xml.Root.Elements("ProductReceipt")
                from prodId in productReceipt.Attributes("ProductId")
                where prodId.Value == productName
                select prodId.Value;

return = result.Any();
```

`xml.Root` is the `Receipt` element, the `Elements` method returns a sequence of elements with the given name, and the `Attributes` method returns a sequence of attributes with the given name. From the XML example you provided, I'm not quite sure if the `ProductId` attribute will hold the name of the product. If it's not so it can be easily changed in the second line of the LINQ query.