# In-App Purchase Receipt Parsing In WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xml-parsing, in-app-purchase, receipt

I try to write a phonegap WP8 in app purchase plugin. In my plugin, I want to get "order id". I know it's possible, so receipt has an unique id.

When I try this,

```
string receipt = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productListing.ProductId, false);
```

receipt string is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <Receipt Version="1.0" CertificateId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2012/store/receipt">
  <ProductReceipt PurchasePrice="1.0" PurchaseDate="10:32:31 AM" Id="0fba8b37-95ed-4c57-b16a-00f9ac25d696" AppId="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" ProductId="img.2" ProductType="Consumable" PublisherUserId="00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" PublisherDeviceId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" MicrosoftProductId="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" /> 
- <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
- <SignedInfo>
  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-xxxx-00000000" /> 
  <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /> 
- <Reference URI="">
- <Transforms>
  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /> 
  </Transforms>
  <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /> 
  <DigestValue>whocares</DigestValue> 
  </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>whocares</SignatureValue> 
  </Signature>
  </Receipt>
```

How can I get Id (it's attribute of ProductReceipt element) from this string? [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541532/2877080) and any other similar links are not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Actually, it was very easy.

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(receipt);
XElement productReceipt = xml.Root.Elements().FirstOrDefault();
string orderId = productReceipt.Attribute("Id").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your receipt it doesn't contain "order-id" But it has "Id" in "Productreceipt".
I think you need that Id.

Here is a method I Implemented for my project to parse xml receipt. It will provide  Dictionary in response and you can eaisly find Id in dictionary.

```
private string ParseReceiptData(string xmlReceipt)
    {
        Dictionary AttributeDict = new Dictionary();
        var xd = XDocument.Parse(xmlReceipt).Descendants();
        foreach (var node in xd)
        {
            if (node.Name.LocalName.Equals("ProductReceipt"))
            {
                var attribute = node.Attributes();
                foreach (var attrib in attribute)
                {
                    AttributeDict.Add(attrib.Name.LocalName, attrib.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        var purchaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(AttributeDict["PurchaseDate"]);
        var Expdate = purchaseDate.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(30)).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
        AttributeDict.Add("ExpiryDate", Expdate);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AttributeDict);
    }
```

Comment: I try it. But the variable "attribute" was null. Anyway, I found answer. Thanks for response.

Comment: Its returning value for me by simple parsing. Don't know why you getting null, And since you found answer no need to check further.